# Documenting variables in a Python module

Tags: python, documentation, python-3.x

I am writing a Python module that uses Numpy. I am trying to follow the [Numpy docstring format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format). In many of my functions, the same parameters show up. It seems repetitive to explain what they are in more than one function from the same module. Is there a common practice when dealing with this?

Comment: Have you considered changing API to be concise? Like extracting an object or two to encapsulate some state?

Comment: Admittedly, I'm not sure what that means. I'm more so doing scientific computing than software development

Comment: Nevermind, discussing this here would be ignorant to your question. My point was to remove argument repetition instead of documenting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a verbose parameter description to class or package documentation and add short reference to it from every function documentation.
Basically, bite the bullet. This can't be automated or conveniently enhanced more.